# Get error when try to create "username" branch when "username/feature-name" branch existed on origin but now deleted

Tags: git, git-branch

I earlier created branch like:

```
git branch "username/feature-name"
```

Now the branch is merged to develop and I don't need that anymore instead I need branch: "username"

But when I run:

```
git branch "username"
```

I get below error message:

> cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/username':
>   'refs/heads/username/feature-name' exists; cannot create
>   'refs/heads/username'

How I can solve this?

I run

```
git fetch origin develop
```

but that did not solve the issue.

If I do:

```
git branch -a
```

I get below branches along with other:

```
...
"username/feature-name"
"remote/origin/username/feature-name"
...
...
```

If I run:

```
git remote show origin
```

I get:

**under remote branches:**

```
 Remote branches:
  refs/remotes/origin/username/feature-name stale (use 'git remote prune' to 
  remove)
```

This does not show up under local branch.

I am not sure what git remote prune would do so please need guidance.

Let me know if question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run:

```
git remote prune origin // To remove stale branch from remote
```

Run:

```
git branch -d username/feature-name // to remove branch from local
```

This Solved issue.

Reference: [Git prune](https://bruck.me/2016/01/04/git-command-of-the-day-git-remote-prune/)